# Using array of maps in Jasper Reports/Scala

Tags: scala, jasper-reports

I have the following Scala code that generates a Jasper Report using an array of maps as data source (JRMapArrayDataSource). This works fine if all the values have the same type (such as String), but when I try to combine strings and integers in the HashMap I get a compilation error:

```
 val map1 = new HashMap[String,Object](Map("f1"->"aaa1", "f2"-> "aaa2", "f3" -> 1 ))
 val map2 = new HashMap[String,Object](Map("f1"->"bbb1", "f2"-> "bbb2", "f3" -> 2 ))

 val dataSource = new JRMapArrayDataSource(Array(map1, map2));

 val params = new HashMap[String,Object]()
 val jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("test1.jasper", params, dataSource);
 JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "test1.pdf");
```

In the line of map1 and map2 I get the following:

> overloaded method constructor HashMap with alternatives: (x$1:
>   java.util.Map[_ <: String, _ <:
>   Object])java.util.HashMap[String,Object]  (x$1:
>   Int)java.util.HashMap[String,Object] cannot be applied to
>   (scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any])

Since I have in the report two string fields (`f1` and `f2`) and one int field (`f3`) I need to have this combination in the HashMap. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use Any:

```
val map1 = new HashMap[String,Any](Map("f1"->"aaa1", "f2"-> "aaa2", "f3" -> 1 ))
```